# Is it possible to connect multiple AWS EC2 instances in the same region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have eight EC2 instances of the same type. Is it possible to connect them to form a "cluster" that would allow computations as if all the cores of the individual instances were in one big EC2 instance?

I've looked everywhere but couldn't find anything for my purpose.

Comment: No, you can't make a single application instance or operating system make use of all those separate resources. It is just like having multiple physical servers, you can't have a single app running on all those separate pieces of hardware. There might be a solution to scale your app across those instances but you need to provide much more information about your use case if you want help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but it is possible to increase computation power by adding more nodes, in fact it is **horizontal scaling**.

thew way highly depends on task you want to process. Perhaps you should look at EMR (MapReduce), it is at AWS too.

If you want just split load among many nodes and this is a *properly* designed website, then you need an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB). Just for example, WordPress in this sense is not properly designed because requires additional efforts to manage uploads (plugin, Elastic File System or something like that)

If you want just split load among many nodes and this is *not*  http-based application then SQS may help to distribute the load.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect them into a private VPC and then write some code to make your apps use all the resources like if they were in one computer, but there is no simple way to do it and depends on which apps you are using. Some 3D apps like Cinema4D allow to render a project in different machines, for example.